# How to use a timer?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to change the background, but I want to change it using a timer. for example in the morning I have a background and evening I have another background. But I don't know what to use in Android. and if you have an example to follow. any idea?

Comment: use alarmmanager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I understand what you mean, do you want to:

-Change the background after a time or
-change the background at different daytimes?

To accomplish the second one, I would set a switch into your OnCreate() method (or any other place e.g. OnResume(), a button click) that looks for the Time with

```
Time t = new Time();  
t.setToNow();
```

and then decides what Image to use

Comment: Assuming the OP is happy with only changing the background when the app starts up, then I think this is the most elegant solution of them all. If the OP actually wants the background to change while the app is running, this is *still* an excellent solution, you just want to run the test in other places as well, such as during button presses, etc.